# module' object has no attribute 'find_template_source satchmo-django

Tags: django, satchmo

after finished installing satchmo in django1.4 . 
i got this error "module' object has no attribute 'find_template_source"

```
AttributeError at /
'module' object has no attribute 'find_template_source'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    "link url"
Django Version: 1.4.8
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'module' object has no attribute 'find_template_source'
Exception Location: /home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_app_plugins-0.1.0-py2.7.egg/app_plugins/templatetags/app_plugins.py in template_exists, line 162
Python Executable:  /home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/prabhakaran/softwares/satchmo/store',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_threaded_multihost-1.4_1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sorl_thumbnail-12.1c-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_livesettings-1.4_14-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_keyedcache-1.5.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3b1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Babel-1.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snowballstemmer-1.2.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils-0.12-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pygments-2.0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.7.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.8.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz-2014.9-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MarkupSafe-0.23-py2.7-linux-i686.egg',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/South-1.0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Satchmo-0.9.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_app_plugins-0.1.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_caching_app_plugins-0.1.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/prabhakaran/virtual/dj1.4_satchmo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '../../apps',
 '']
Server time:    Wed, 19 Nov 2014 06:02:54 -0800


  "

module' object has no attribute 'find_template_source

"
```

Comment: Can you include the stack trace as well?

Comment: did u mean this package ..https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-sql-stacktrace  ..????

Comment: No, I mean the traceback from the exception.

Comment: sry .. i didnt understand ur comment , am just beginner in django.so an u explain a little bit . or comment any example link